# What was the penultimate flight of the TCA plane that crashed near Vancouver in 1947?

Tags: aviation-history, accidents, canada, flight-schedules

In his 1975 book *An Almanac of Words at Play*, [Willard R. Espy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_R._Espy) recounts the following:

> En route from Montreal to Vancouver in 1947, we sat down in Calgary, where a wire from my boss changed my itinerary and I deplaned—the only passenger to do so. The plane proceeded, and vanished in the sloughs around Vancouver. As far as I know, the wreckage was never found.

I was curious as to what flight this might have been.  The only close match I can find is [Trans-Canada Air Lines Lockheed 18-08A Lodestar, Fin 53 CF-TDF, that went missing while on approach to Vancouver on 28 April 1947](http://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19470428-0).  (Its wreckage was eventually found in 1994.)  However, this flight departed from Lethbridge, whereas Espy writes that his plane departed from Calgary.

I can see two likely explanations for this:

1. Espy was wrong about what happened to his plane after he disembarked in Calgary.  It must have continued on to Vancouver without incident, and when he later heard the news about a missing plane en route to Vancouver, he mistakenly believed it was the same one he had been on.
2. Espy misremembered which airport he stopped at; his plane was actually scheduled to go from Montreal to Vancouver via Lethbridge.  So he really was in Lethbridge, not Calgary, and indeed narrowly avoided being killed in the plane crash.

Supporting evidence for the second explanation might be gleaned from 53 CF-TDF's itinerary *before* it departed from Lethbridge.  Is there any way of finding out if this plane arrived at Lethbridge from Montreal before continuing on towards Vancouver?